# Play evolutions not updating the status to applied

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-evolutions

We are using play framework with java and use evolutions for the regular schema changes. Usually evolutions are working great but, sometimes when an evolutions script is heavy (ex: doing an alter statement on a table with around 5M records) they are getting stuck in applying_up. There were no issues to the script and all the intended changes are already applied to the tables. play_evolutions table do not have anything stated in last_problem column.

I know the code is responsible to update the status, but based on the situation it seems like the database changes are applying properly but somehow it is failing to communicate with the java thread and java was not able to update the status. I have checked the wait_timeout, interactive_timeout and they are 28800 seconds which is more than the actual query is taking.

Please provide any suggestion on how can we tackle this. Thanks

**Setup:** play framework with Java

**Database:** MySQL RDS

**Play version:** 2.8.18 (this is irrelevant since the issue is there
for earlier versions too)

**mysql-connector:** 8.0.30

Answer (score 0):

With your update script weighing 5M, your problem looks like what is described in the last paragraph of [Managing database evolutions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Evolutions#Evolution-storage-and-limitations), named *Evolution storage and limitations* :

> Evolutions are stored in your database in a table called
> play_evolutions. A Text column stores the actual evolution script.
> Your database probably has a 64kb size limit on a text column. To work
> around the 64kb limitation you could: manually alter the
> play_evolutions table structure changing the column type or
> (preferred) create multiple evolutions scripts less than 64kb in size.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The Query to run the migration is very small. It is an alter statement with ADD column. It is never going to cross cross 64KB. also if the text files size exceeds, I believe database will throw a Constraint violation exception.